# Powershell - open new console as different user in the same window - runas, netonly, NoNewWindow

Tags: powershell, windows-authentication

I need to open Powershell console (within the same window) as different user with `/netonly` option.
I would like to avoid typing manually passwords, because I will use this console to run some scripts automatically.

I've tried few ways:

**1**

```
runas.exe /netonly /user:myDomain\myTestUser powershell.exe
```

works properly, except:

1. Opens new window
2. Ask me for password (as long as I know it is not possible to combine `/netonly` and `/savecred` with `runas`)

**2**

`$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myDomain\myTestUser", (ConvertTo-SecureString "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process powershell -Credential $Cred -NoNewWindow`

Unfortunately this option doesn't allow `/netonly` switch

**3**

I used script from:
https://github.com/FuzzySecurity/PowerShell-Suite/blob/master/Invoke-Runas.ps1

and executed:
`Invoke-Runas -User "myTestUser" -Password "myPassword" -Domain "myDomain" -Binary C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -LogonType 0x2`

this works properly...except it opens new window

---

Is there any workaround / is it possible to combine functionality of `/netonly` switch from `runas` and `NoNewWindow` from Start-Process in Powershell

Comment: I guess that it might be easiest to tweak the third option (?). Try to attach to just opened new window (through `Debug-Process`?). Unfortunately in this case I receive an error

Comment: ---------------------------
Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger
---------------------------
Select a debugger to attach to powershell.exe [10344]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.

Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------